# cx_oracle gettype returns invalid dataype over dblink

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am able to desc the datatype over the db link using:

`desc schema.datatype@dblink;`

However when running in cx_oracle using:

`con.gettype('schema.datatype@dblink')`

It returns the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00902: invalid datatype`

Comment: [From the docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.gettype), `gettype` is supposed to be passed the name of a type; the *name* you're passing isn't valid. The function just doesn't seem to do what you think? (You'd probably need to query the data dictionary, or run a query against the table and look at its metadata, to get the equivalent of `desc`).

Comment: @AlexPoole Could you elaborate? I am able to get it to work fine by using the connection directly without a dblink ie `con.gettype('schema.datatype')` works